# Set Visual Studio 2015 Compiler to VS 2010 version

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I'm a student and i'm using Visual Studio 2015 to learn C++.

I need to set my compiler so it will check my code the same as Visual Studio 2010's compiler so no errors show up on my disciple's end who was instructed to check our code in 2010 environment.
Is there any way i can do that?
sorry for any bad English and i hope you understand my question.

thanks in advance!

Comment: That is not possible, VS2015 has *many* changes due to the three C++ language revisions.  That cannot be turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible by changing "Platform Toolset":

[image]

Full details [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/24/stuck-on-an-older-toolset-version-move-to-visual-studio-2015-without-upgrading-your-toolset/)

**EDIT:**
As correctly mentioned by @HansPassant in the comment you need VS2010 toolset installed. You can download and install VS2010 C++ Express edition

Comment: That's rather misleading, you do need to explain that the user actually has to have VS2010 installed to get that toolset option.  If he had then he wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: thank you!!!! this was driving me nuts! how do i get all the other toolsets? i can only see two and both are 2015

Comment: @HansPassant You are right! I will edit my answer now... But still there are reasons why this switch exists. Many people have VS2010 but still want to use later editions as IDE. There are many advantages

Comment: sorry for taking so long to respond.. do i need to install VS2010 express in order to get the toolset? can't i just install the toolset like an expansion or something?

Comment: I mentioned VS2010 express as one possible option, I never tried others but requirement is simple - v100 toolset should be installed in the system